# Where is TexLive2012 after installing it via ISO?

Tags: latex

I downloaded the latest TexLive2012 iso and installed it on my computer by running the install-tl script, I chosed the default installnation, and it finished successfully, but where can I find the executable binarys?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Not really an answer, but rather an alternative for next time is the [TeXLive Backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa) which provides TeXLive 2012 for Precise as Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`which tex` should give you an answer, if it does not, you may have skipped the **Post-install: setting PATH** step from http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html, which basically reuires you to add binaries path to your path environment. In my `~/.bashrc` I have

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should not check the install option "Create symlinks in system directories" when you install.

Perhaps, it would be better to use the GUI to install Texlive 2012, by using:

```
./install-tl --gui
```

Before you start the GUI installation, install these two packages.

```
sudo apt-get install perl-tk p7zip
```

And then, you can run the Texlive installation.